# Hadoop HDFS: How to set hostname:9000 instead of localhost:9000

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs, microsoft-distributed-file-system

How can I set the IP address that Hadoop HDFS should listen on? Currently, when I run `netstat` I see its on `127.0.0.1:9000`. This makes access HDFS impossible from another node in the cluster. I get `connection refused error` when running application.

I want it to appear as `my-machine-name:9000` instead of `127.0.0.1:9000`. My `core-site.xml` file is

```
<property>
      <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
      <value>my-machine-name:9000/</value>
</property>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add/edit this line in `/etc/host` file on your local machine(client node)

```
127.0.0.1 localhost my-machine-name
```

Similarly add this line to your cluster nodes `/etc/hosts` where 198.1.1.1 being public ip of client node(this command should give you public ip: `ipconfig` or `hostname -i` - make sure to run it on client node)

```
198.1.1.1 my-machine-name
```

Comment: Just did exactly so. When job running, `call from cluster-node: connection refused.`
so from cluster node, I do `nmap -p 9000 my-machine-name` I get `connection refused`. my-machine-name is the driver code.

Comment: Check on your client node that if something else is running on port 9000  `netstat -a|grep 9000`- also check firewall settings